# Social media - like buttons with direct links?

Tags: facebook-like, social-media

I'm wondering if there is a way to insert a "custom" like button with just a link like

```
<a href="www.a.link">Like us on FB</a>
```

for sites like FaceBook , StumbleUpon, diggit etc. Even though if my website does not have a page in those sites?